# HAproxy redirect exact URL

Tags: haproxy

Hi i need redirect only `www.example.com/foo` in `foo.example.com`, if try in this way:

```
redirect location http://foo.example.com code 301 if { path_beg /foo }
```

all `/foo` (include `foo.example.com/foo`) redirect to wrong URL, how can redirect only  `www.example.com/foo`?

Thanks

Comment: If you only want this to redirect in case of certain domain names, why don't you include that in your condition?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you mean by "wrong URL" and provide some examples of what it does now, compared to what you expect. The `path_beg` fetch means "path begins with."